# Get value of input radio buttons and separate label values as an object?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, object

I have a list of Labels and then two radio inputs for each label. I want to pass the name of the label and the value of the input and use them to create an object in my component. The labels for the radio buttons are not associated with the input as standard labels as they need to be Yes/No values. It looks like this:

```
<ul class="field-labels">
    <li *ngFor="let label of labels">
        {{label}}
    </li>
</ul>
<div *ngFor="let label of labels; let i=index;" class="form">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input  id="{{'radio-yes-'+i}}" name="{{'radio-'+i}}"
                    type="radio" value="Yes"
                    [attr.data-field-label]="label">
            <label for="{{'radio-yes-'+i}}">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input  id="{{'radio-no-'+i}}" name="{{'radio-'+i}}"
                    type="radio" value="No"
                    [attr.data-field-label]="label">
            <label for="{{'radio-no-'+i}}">No</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Frontend:
----------------------------
Correct size?   Yes ⚪ No
Good value?     Yes ⚪ No
```

What I have then is a button that on submit will need to get each Label and the Value of the radio inputs and store them as an object like this:

```
{
  "correctSize": "Yes",
  "goodValue": "Yes"
  ...
}
```

I'm passing the label to a custom data attribute but I'm not sure this will be needed. I'm hoping to use the `value` of the radio input and the `data-field-label` to get the object I need above.

Comment: what does your labels object that you are looping over look like?

Comment: At the moment I'm getting this back: ``{ "Correct size?", "Good value?"...}``

Comment: I mean the loop you are using in  *ngFor="let label of labels ; I think you would need a tag like alias : 'correctSize' on your original loop of labels and then push that into your results obj

Comment: I think that might be possible, but I'm not sure how to get the Yes/No values from the input radios and tie them to the label values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a solution would be to use forms.

If your logic becomes more complex, you should consider having a look at **Reactive Forms**.

But, in this case, **Template Driven Forms** can do the job:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
    <div *ngFor="let label of labels; index as idx">
    <label>{{ label }}</label>
    <ng-container [ngModelGroup]="label">
        <input ngModel [name]="'answer.' + idx" value="yes" type="radio">
        <input ngModel="yes" [name]="'answer.' + idx" value="no" type="radio">
    </ng-container>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

```
labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'];

onSubmit (value) {
  console.log('value', value)
}
```

[ng-run example](https://ng-run.com/edit/6oOMsLWv4KhbgBEYuUw9)